# Filtering Layers based on types in ArcGIS

Tags: arcobjects

I want to loop through all the layers in TOC in ArcGIS and report Raster and Vector Layers. I want to see how many layer are raster and how many are vector. I can access the layers using:

```
IEnumLayer pEnumLayer = pMap.get_Layers(null, true);
```

and loop the layers in Enum, but how do I determine which layer is Raster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using [IMap.get_Layers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/Layers_Property/001200000m9t000000/) you can supply a UID with the intended type, for example:

```
UID pFeatureLayersUID = new UIDClass();
pFeatureLayersUID.Value = "{40A9E885-5533-11d0-98BE-00805F7CED21}";
IEnumLayer pMapLayers = gMap.get_Layers(pFeatureLayersUID, true);
```

Will get you all the feature layers (Vector) in your current map recursively... normally you would get all your vector layers, then all your raster layers but I suppose you can get *all* your layers and branch accordingly...

To find out what they are you need to use the coclasses of [ILayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/ArcObjects_NET/componenthelp/index.html#/ILayer_Interface/0012000006z1000000/) (there's quite a few of them):

```
ILayer pLayer = pMapLayers.Next();
if (pLayer.Valid) // important, make sure it's not broken
{
    if (pLayer is IFeatureLayer)
    { 
    }
    else if (pLayer is IRasterLayer)
    { 
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a useful [KB page](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/31115) by ESRI that tells you how to find GUIDS.

Comment: Here's another one not using RegEdit http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=194976 ... some system administrators disable RegEdit.